# Ajax call not executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following function:

```
Recorder.uploadAudio = function(blob, filename){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event){
        var data;
        data = event.target.result;
        $.post( "upload.php", { fname: filename, data: data } );
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      $.get( "get_files.php", function( data ) {
        $('#clips').html(data);
      });
    }
```

The sript upload.php saves a file to a server and get_files.php refreshes the file list(it loads all audio files in a folder and display them in a list.) When I debug the script the upload.php doesn't load, it stops on the data = `event.target.result` line. And, blob argument is loaded fine and it represents an audio file as it should.

Edit: Here is upload.php code:

```
<?php

function is_dir_empty($dir) {
  if (!is_readable($dir)) return NULL; 
  $handle = opendir($dir);
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}

function get_latest_index($path) {
    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = ''; 

    $d = dir($path);

    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
      // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
      if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
        $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
        $latest_filename = $entry;
      }
    }
    $latest_index = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$latest_filename);
    $latest_index = (int)$latest_index;
    $latest_index++;
    if ($latest_index < "10") {
        $latest_index = "0" . $latest_index;
    }

    return $latest_index;
}

// pull the raw binary data from the POST array
$data = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
// decode it
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
// print out the raw data,


$path = "audio/"; 
$d = dir($path);

if (is_dir_empty($d)) {
    $fname = "MyRecording00";
}
else{
    $fname = "MyRecording" . get_latest_index($path);
}



$filename = "audio/" . $fname . ".wav";
echo $filename;
// write the data out to the file
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean it "stops"? Does it throw an error?

Comment: I set the debbuger in browser on the line I mentioned and on the next line with the jquery post request, and it just steps over it and goes to the next ajax call(jquery get request for get_files.php).

Comment: what did you expect to happen there?  `$.post` is an asynchronous function.

Comment: @Igor I would understand if my second function executes before the first one.The thing than happens is that my post function doesn't execute at all, because it doesn't create a new audio file as it should

Comment: @user3362334 _"The thing than happens is that my post function doesn't execute at all, because it doesn't create a new audio file as it should"_ You can check network tab at `console` to determine if `$.post()` sends data to `url` . How is audio file created at `php` ? Note, `$.post()` does not create the file; `$.post()` only sends `{ fname: filename, data: data }` to server. Note also that `data` is a `data URI`

Comment: @guest271314 I updated the question with the content of upload.php. It seems like the file is loaded, but the new audio file isn't showing up

Comment: _"but the new audio file isn't showing up"_ Isn't showing up where ? As a file in the filesystem ? , or as a response from `$.get()` ?

Comment: @guest271314 It wasn't showing up in the filesystem either. I already had some audio files in my audio folder, the last one was MyRecording67.wav. And the post function was constantly returning MyRecording16.wav and overwriting it. I saw that in response in network tab. When I deleted all the files from my audio folder,it all works fine. I don't know why this happened but thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`FileReader` `onload` event is asynchronous; `$.post()` and `$.get()` return results asynchronously. Try including both `$.get()` and `$.post()`  within `onload` event of `FileReader`; call `$.get()` within complete callback of of `$.post()`

```
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event){
        var data;
        data = event.target.result;
        $.post( "upload.php", { fname: filename, data: data } )
        .then(function() {
          $.get( "get_files.php", function( data ) {
            $('#clips').html(data);
          })
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```